# postgres IN clause through python psycopg

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to execute the below postgres query through python psycopg2

```
SELET * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Below is the python code for the same:

```
def get_usernames(userids):
    connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=userdb user=guest host=example.com")
    connection.autocommit = True
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid IN {}".format(userids))
    return cursor

userids=[1,2,3,4,5]
get_usernames(userids)
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...from users WHERE userid IN {1,2...
```

I'm used to pymysql. This is new to me. Let me know what is my mistake.

Comment: `userids` is a list, you can't just interpolate that into a query.

Comment: And please copy and paste errors, don't type them in manually. The error message would say `WHERE userid in [1, 2, ...` at the very least.

Comment: In `pymysql` we can send a list and get this done... However for time being im iterating through `for` loop for all `userids`.. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?..

Comment: All you need is a `%s` query parameter for the values: `cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid IN %s", (tuple(userids),))` (but do pass in the ids as a tuple).

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is the error message i got .. I didn't type in.. Pasted as it is.. All others were just stacktraces

Comment: The actual error message produced is `'syntax error at or near "["\nLINE 1: SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]\n                                                   ^\n'` (whitespace before the `^` collapsed from 51 to 1 space by the way SO renders comments). Note the square brackets and spacing in that error message, there is no `{` curly brace and there are spaces after each comma.
`

Comment: well..  I just modified the error message from actual code..   :-) ... Never expected you'd pinpoint like this :-D ...

Comment: Exactly, and for future questions: *don't do that*, as you may be removing critical information that we may need to diagnose issues.

Comment: sure.. thanks for the feedback and answering on time..